# Will Upgrading Ram on Low End PC Make Core Sync faster?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, memory

I am a newbie to bitcoin. I am trying to sync a full node on my low end PC: 2g RAM, dual-core 2ghz, 250 gb regular HDD. It is in pruned mode. The initial 15% synced in a few days but now the process is fluctuating wildly around 2-7 weeks. Suffice to say it is very slow.

My main question is: how much will adding some RAM improve the syncing speed? And will adding new RAM reset the blockchain download?

I have already adjusted these settings: dbcach=900, banscore=10, listen=0

I am worried that putting in the RAM will "reset" the blockchain download and I will have to start syncing from 0% again. This already happened to me when I was tinkering with the dbcache setting - Which I will have to do again in order to take advantage of any new RAM(right?).

Anyway I hope that was a coherent question. Any response is very appreciated. :)

Comment: I suspect network bandwidth is the limiting factor for many people.

Comment: Your HDD is most likely the limiting factor. What operating system do you use? Changing dbcache does not require starting download all over again. Something else happen there. You might want to take a look into debug.log which can be found in your datadir.

Answer (score 1):

> The initial 15% synced in a few days but now the process is fluctuating wildly around 2-7 weeks. Suffice to say it is very slow.

This happens because the very first blocks were pretty munch empty, so it's easy to verify.

> I am worried that putting in the RAM will "reset" the blockchain download and I will have to start syncing from 0% again.

No, it doesn't.

There are numerous things that impact how fast your Bitcoin Core will sync, your HD speed, internet bandwidth, RAM, how good is your CPU… That said, `-dbcache` changes how many things we cache, cached things = less disk access, so it should increase performance, BUT it's not a linear thing; more RAM not necessarily means faster sync.